# How does one validate an entire site?

Tags: html, validation, firewall

I realize there's the W3C validator, which works great for one page.  There's also the perl install they provide, but it seems to not work on a Mac or it's buggy.

Given that

1) I have an entire set of local files

How do I

a) Validate the entire set

b) do it behind a firewall

c) do it simply without installing anything on my computer?  (i.e., is there a web service?)

Or is this just futile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some sites that can do batch validation, like [WDG HTML Validator](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/), so that you can validate multiple pages at once, but I believe it is only for html. I don't know if there are similar validators for other languages. I will keep looking to see what else I can find

I also found a link to use w3c validator for batch validation [Here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200505/validating_an_entire_site/)

EDIT*

You could also use something like dreamweaver in xhtml format, but I find it doesn't do a very good job of it.

Comment: Even though your answer doesn't meet all my requirements, I have yet to find anything more universal.

Answer (score 3):

Try this bulk w3c html validator here

http://www.bulkseotools.com/bulk-w3c-validator.php

You can enter up to 500 urls, the tool will check them all and will return number of errors, warnings. If error found, click review link to see error details. This tool is accurate, it uses W3c validator engine. The site also has bulk css validator tool, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it before but [W3CLove](https://www.w3clove.com/) looks really useful for this problem. The plans are reasonably priced and they have a money back guarantee.

Comment: W3CLove was later renamed as [Site Validator](https://sitevalidator.com).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Having the same problem I think the best thing to do is to do it manually. I have a system that requires logging in before you can actually see pages. and the validate.w3c.org/check site seems to break, So the best way to go about it is to. Install validator locally. And go about it that way it makes way more sense.
BTW. you would have to check pages individually as there can be number of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can MoutValid, it is an online tool to get an entire standards compliance report of your website. Just provide a URL like your sitemap page. You can look at ti at: https://www.macmout.com/moutvalid/